# I can't add the serilog.dll into sql Server assemblys

Tags: serilog

Actually, I'm working on developping an SQL project using visual studio 2019 within framework 4.8 . this project contains three dependencies (sub projects ) referenced as dll into my main sql project. one of them is a serilog project. So, i v generated all the solution and it s ok. but when i tried to create an assembly in sql server, i couldn't create it. i recieve a message shown below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qomSS.png)

can anyone help me resolve this issues.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear: The Serilog assemblies reference a different assembly `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0` which has not been added to SQL Server yet... So you need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions` to SQL Server first, before adding the Serilog assemblies.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's not about adding this dll file because i already added it in the assembly. but the problem is that sql sevrer did not recognize the file ...  finally, want to thank you again dear friend. i resolve the issue and it works now ...